# Returning Information in PHP

Tags: php, forms

The issue I am having, is that I have a form:

```
<form  method="POST" action="return.php" >
    <div class="form_description">
        <h2>Production Scheduler</h2>
        <p>Enter the quantity of a product</p>
    </div>

    <p>ET63 <input type="text" name="1"/></p> 
    <p>ET61 <input type="text" name="2"/></p>  
    <p>ET83 <input type="text" name="3"/></p>   
    <p>ET81 <input type="text" name="4"/></p>   
    <p>ET85 <input type="text" name="5"/> </p>  
    <p>ET103 <input type="text" name="6"/> </p>  
    <p>ET153 <input type="text" name="7"/> </p>  
    <p>ET6SCORE <input type="text" name="8"/></p>   

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Which is fine. Everything works how I want it.  The `name="#"` isn't actually numbers, but for privacy is changed.

So the issue is, I want to test to make sure I am getting results and removing the extra info, but I can't get my php to run.  Here is the return php:

```php
<body>
<?php 
    for ($x =0; $x > 0; $x++) {
        if ($_POST[$x] >= 1) {
            echo $_POST[$x];
        }
    }
?>
</body>
```

I have tried casting the `if ($POST[$x] >= 1)`. I am fairly new at PHP and such (About a week old).

Everything is .php

I am running it on a php enabled server

Comment: So what happens when you run the code?

Comment: Start debugging. You should first dump the entire contents of the $_POST variable. `echo '<pre>' . var_export($_POST, true) . '</pre>';`

Comment: That for loop won't do anything. *for x=0 loop whilst bigger than 0*

Comment: `for($x =0; $x > 0; $x++)` -- this doesn't look like a loop. `$x` starts with `0` and it loops while `$x` is greater than `0` -- which never happen. Read about the [`for` control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) in PHP.

Comment: Your loop doesn't work, as others have pointed out before, which is a blessed relief, too, because `for($x = 0;$x >=0; ++$x)` is an infinite loop. You're also treating `$_POST` as a zero-indexed array, but your elements have names ranging from 1 to 8, and there's a submit key in there too. The keys are all strings anyway, so perhaps consider using the more suitable `foreach ($_POST as $k => $v)` loop

Answer (score 1):

<s>Your loop won't end because the condition will always result to `true`.</s> 
Your loop won't even start because it is `false` to begin with.
Maybe change it to something like:

```
for($x =0; $x < count($_POST); $x++)
{
    if($_POST[$x] >= 1)
    {
        echo $_POST[$x];
    }
}
```

This makes the max number of `$_POST` elements the limit of your loop. But usually, just like what is in the comment, what we do to check the `$_POST` (or any variable actually) is with the use of [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

> This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

Comment: Your loop won't work either. It should be `<` not `>`

Comment: And they don't work because the condition results in **false**, not true.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, updating

Comment: Don't use `count($_POST)`, an associative array should be iterated over using `foreach`, not `for`. it's also better to call `count` once, instead of on every iteration: `for ($i = 0, $j = count($arr); $i < $j; ++$i)`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I'm now confused, you told me not to use it, but then you used it. anyway, it will still be valid even on associative arrays if the goal is to limit the loop to the number of elements of the array. I also prefer the use of `foreach` but for the sake of the OP who is practically new to PHP, I'd rather introduce him to `var_dump()` than any kind of looping just to check the `$_POST`

Comment: @Morcen: A `for` loop will work, but you won't be able do do anything useful inside the array, because you don't have the keys. Therefore, use`foreach`. I'm saying you shouldn't use `for`, but if you ever _do_ use `for`, it's better to assign the return value of `count` to a var, instead of counting the number of elements on each iteration

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Doing anything useful with the array is not what the OP wants, or even needs. He just wants to display the value of each `$_POST` element, rendering the array keys useless. But in real-life PHP programming, we are in agreement

Comment: @Morcen: If the array is associative, you can't display the values with a `for` loop. You need the keys. With a for loop, especially one that starts at 0 (look at the markup, that key won't exists), you can't display the values, so a for loop just doesn't make sense here

Answer (score 1):

You made an error in your loop :

```
for($x =0; $x > 0; $x++) {
         if($_POST[$x] >= 1)
         {
             echo $_POST[$x];
         }
}
```

It will stop at its first iteration. You ask to continue while `$x > 0`, its initial value. So the first iteration, you have `if 0 > 0`. So it stops.

You should try something like that :

```
$limit = count($_POST);
for ($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++) {
    if ($_POST[$x] >= 1) {
        echo $_POST[$x];
    }
}
```

By the way, if the keys of your `$_POST` aren't numbers, try something like that, with a `foreach` :

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != $whatIWantToExclude) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for($x =0; $x > 0; $x++) {` isn't infinite, it never _starts_: `$x = 0`, then `$x > 0` (or `0 > 0`, which is false) <-- it's the same as `while (false) {`. Also: don't use `count($_POST)`, the keys are strings! use `foreach`